# Mathematica palettes in Wolfram Desktop

Tags: palettes

Apparently Wolfram Desktop is missing some useful [palettes](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1148695). How can I install them properly? Where would I download Writing Assistant from for example?

Comment: This had better not be true because I was just told (assured and reassured) that Desktop would be **indistinguishable** from Mathematica in every way (except for the stupid Home Edition banner).